# How to increment offset in FeedMe 2.0

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm trying to decide if FeedMe would be a good choice to sync Craft with a fairly large Airtable database (more than 5k records). I'm inclined to say no just on general principle but I've done some quick tests and everything seems to work fairly well. For my next step in testing I wanted to try a larger sample dataset, but I can't figure out to increment the offset parameter.

When I make a request to Airtable, it returns 100 records, and an offset response that looks like

```
itrEk3iGk6zOddYqC\/recF5XRtrVtf6t0um
```

If I add that offset as a parameter to a new request, I get the next 100 records and a new offset value. So how do I tell FeedMe to automatically re-run the feed with the new offset parameter?

Comment: Just a comment to note that FeedMe does have a pagination feature now. Woohoo!

Answer (score 1):

[Received from the developer on Twitter](https://twitter.com/engramdes/status/1036031189264392192):

> There’s no way to handle pagination or offsets automatically yet I’m
>   afraid. You’d have to roll your own solution to handle this at the
>   moment

I've been thinking about creating a plugin that polls the API and triggers a FeedMe task with a custom offset parameter. It would also need to record the status of the task once it's complete and the offset for the next 100 records as well.